# Kleisli dependencies with Tagless Final style

Tags: scala, scala-cats, kleisli, tagless-final

I am trying to model a dependency using Kleisli. For instance, let's imagine I have the following business logic types:

```
import $ivy.`org.typelevel:cats-core_2.13:2.2.0`
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

trait Decoder[F[_]] {
    def decode(s: String): F[String]
}

trait DatabaseAccess[F[_]] {
    def getData(): F[String]
}

trait BusinessLogicService[F[_]] {
    def getTheProcessedData(): F[String]
}

object BusinessLogicService {
    def make[F[_]: Monad](
        decoder: Decoder[F],
        db: DatabaseAccess[F]
    ): BusinessLogicService[F] =
        new BusinessLogicService[F] {
            override def getTheProcessedData(): F[String] = for {
                str <- db.getData()
                decodedStr <- decoder.decode(str)
            } yield decodedStr
        }
}
```

And now I have the following implementations for Decode and DatabaseAccess:

```
import cats.data.Kleisli
trait DbSession {
    def runQuery(): String
}

type ErrorOr[A] = Either[Throwable, A]

type DbSessionDependency[A] = Kleisli[ErrorOr, DbSession, A]
type NoDependencies[A] = Kleisli[ErrorOr, Any, A]

object PlainDecoder extends Decoder[NoDependencies] {
    override def decode(s: String): NoDependencies[String] =
        Kleisli { _ => Right(s.toLowerCase()) }
}

object SessionedDbAccess extends DatabaseAccess[DbSessionDependency] {
    override def getData(): DbSessionDependency[String] = Kleisli { s =>
        Right(s.runQuery)
    }
}
```

Now when I want to use both objects with the business logic I have a conflict of type:
Kleisli[ErrorOr, DbSession, A] is not compatible with Klesili[ErrorOr, Any, A].

```
val businessLogic: BusinessLogicService[DbSessionDependency] = 
    BusinessLogicService.make(PlainDecoder, SessionedDbAccess)
```

What would be the most "correct" way of composing the classes like this? I don't want to make my decoder to require the database session and I'm not really into creating a copy/wrapper around the Decoder as well.

Answer (score 3):

`Kleisli` (as in Cats' `ReaderT` monad implementation) is contravariant at input type:

```
final case class Kleisli[F[_], -A, B](run: A => F[B]) { self =>
...
```

which means that `Kleisli[ErrorOr, DbSession, A]` is not a subtype of `Kleisli[ErrorOr, Any, A]` and cannot be upcased to it.

It's the other way round, `Kleisli[ErrorOr, Any, A]` is a subtype of `Kleisli[ErrorOr, DbSession, A]`.

If you think that `Kleisli[F, In, Out]` here models `In => F[Out]` then you can notice that `DbSession => F[Out]` is accepting less inputs than `Any => F[Out]`. You could use `Any => F[Out]` as `DbSession => F[Out]` but not the other way round because all `DbSession` inputs are also valid `Any` inputs, but not all `Any` inputs are valid `DbSession` inputs (someone can pass e.g. `Unit` or `Int`). So the only safe way is to make input more specific (function defined for less specific input can always handle more specific input).

This is modeled by contravariance in `In` parameter, meaning that supertypes are always more specific. So in your case you cannot expect the inferred type to be `Kleisli[ErrorOr, Any, A]`. If you combine two Kleislis, one taking `Any` and the other taking `DbSession` the input inferred should be `Kleisli[ErrorOr, DbSession, A]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're correct in the definition of parameters and the inheritance model. As described in the following post, the main question here: what was I missing to make the compiler treat Decoder[NoDependencies] as a subtype of Decoder[DbSessionDependency]. That worked because Kleisli's second type parameter is contravariant.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the best answer for this from Daniel Ciocîrlan (author of RockTheJVM courses, which are great, btw).

Daniel Ciocîrlan: Kleisli is contravariant in the input type (second type argument), so NoDependencies <: DbSessionDependency.  But since you pass a PlainDecoder in the make factory method, you expect PlainDecoder = Decoder[NoDependencies] <: Decoder[DbSessionDependency]. That can only happen if Decoder is covariant in F. So you need to have Decoder[+F[_]].

So, it works when

```
trait Decoder[+F[_]] {
    def decode(s: String): F[String]
}
```